# How find this value $d+\frac{\sqrt{3}b}{a}$ if such $a^2+2ac-2ac^3-2a^2c^2=bcd+\sqrt{3}acd$

Tags: calculus

**Question:**

> Let $a,b,c,d\in R$.and such $$a^2+b^2=1,c^2+d^2=1$$
>   $$a^2+2ac-2ac^3-2a^2c^2=bcd+\sqrt{3}acd$$

Find the value  $d+\dfrac{\sqrt{3}b}{a}$

I think 
$$a^2+2ac-2ac^3-2a^2c^2=a^2-2ac(ac+c^2-1)=cd(b+\sqrt{3})$$
so
$$a^2-2ac(ac-d^2)=cd(b+\sqrt{3})$$
then I can't works

other idea: let $$a=\cos{x},b=\sin{x},c=\cos{y},d=\sin{y}$$
then we have
$$\cos^2{x}+2\cos{x}\cos{y}-2\cos{x}\cos^2{y}-2\cos^2{x}\cos^2{y}=\sin{x}\cos{y}\sin{y}+\sqrt{3}\cos{x}\cos{y}\sin{y}$$
then we find this value
$$\sin{y}+\dfrac{\sqrt{3}\sin{x}}{\cos{y}}=?$$

This problem is from exam problem

Comment: Since there are only three equations but four variables, in general we can't solve for a, b, c, and d.  Indeed, a quick test with Mathematica shows that d+Sqrt[3]b/a can take on any value from -Infinity to +Infinity, depending on the a, b, c, and d chosen.  Maybe there is a typo?